# In /etc/hosts file why would IPv4 hosts be different from IPv6 hosts?

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6, fqdn, centos8

**Background:** CentOS 8, Digital Ocean droplet.

**Question 1)** I just looked at my hosts file in /etc/hosts and I noticed that hostnames listed under IPv4 and IPv6 are different.  IPv4 lists `example, example.com and mail.example.com` while IPv6 only lists `example example`.  Is this correct?  Intuitively it makes sense to me that they should be the same for both IPv4 and IPv6.

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv4 capable hosts
127.0.0.1 example example.com mail.example.com
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 example example
::1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

Comment: I would suggest that you check if this file matches what Centos 8 creates. If so, ask Centos and/or Redhat. If not, ask Digital Ocean. I don't think anyone else will be able to answer why they did it that way, it looks more like a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo.

One could argue they should be the same, and at the same time it really does not matter because it is only an example value.

While multiple shell scripts etc. could rely on the correct setting of `localhost`, I hope nobody and no tool assumes anything about http://example.com/. (Just in case you are wondering: it is a reserved domain as per [RFC6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761) and IANA put a placeholder page there.)